# Difference between 'to buy' and 'I buy'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have seen that I get confused with words like "buy". If someone says "buy car", is this like "I'm selling a car"?
And if I'm right, "I buy car" means "I bought car". Is that correct?

Comment: 'Buy a car,' can mean someone's telling you to buy a car either for yourself or for them or for someone else because the sentence isn't clear enough. Also, 'I buy car' is not grammatically correct. 'I  buy cars,' means you have the habit of buying cars. 'I want to buy a car,' means you wish to buy one car in the near/far future. 'I bought a car' means you already finished buying a car. I suggest that you work on your grammar and tenses as that'll clear much confusion.

Comment: "Buy car" on its own is not a valid sentence, neither is "I buy car".

Comment: The only acceptable use of "buy" without a subject is the imperative, which has an implicit subject of "you." So the sentence "Buy a car!" is a command that means the same thing as "You should buy a car!"

Comment: No, simple present is for general ideas: I buy a car every year. For example.

Answer (score 1):

"I bought car" is the past tense of "I buy car". But the correct way to use these phrases is "I bought that/the/a/ car", depending on the context. "I'll buy that/the/a car".

Answer (score 1):

Imperative Sentence- Buy a car.

Simple Present Tense- I buy a car. I buy a car every year.

Simple Past Tense- I bought a car. I bought a car last year.